# Get GMTdate from timestamp in PHP

Tags: php, encryption, hash

Here, I am getting **encrypted_string** dynamically and want to check that it is from last one minutes time interval or not. For that i am using difference between two timestamps **(start_time and end_time)**.

I am not getting proper date format in **date_string**.
How do i get **date_string** in gmdate format?

```
$key = "abc";
$current_date = gmdate("Y_m_d_h_i_s");
$encrypted_string = hash_hmac('sha256',$current_date,$key);

$start_time = date("Ymdhis",strtotime($current_date));
$end_time = date("Ymdhis",strtotime($current_date)-59);
for($i=$start_time; $i > $end_time; $i--){
        $date_string = gmdate("Y_m_d_h_i_s",strtotime($i));
        $new_string = hash_hmac('sha256', $date_string,$key);
        if($encrypted_string == $new_string){
               return true;
        } 
}
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You might want to do a var_dump of `strtotime($i)` inside your loop there.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe Tried that. Not working.

Comment: *sigh* … making a debug output at this place was supposed to show you, that strtotime only returns  0 – it can not parse the input date format you are feeding it.